# HAPROXY Access nested value from txn object

Tags: lua, haproxy

I'm using jwtverify to check authentication on haproxy (https://github.com/haproxytech/haproxy-lua-oauth).

It is said in the documentation that you can access claims from the txn object like this: `var(txn.oauth.scope)`. But I need to  access nested data and it seems that I can't manage to access more than one level of the data.

I tried to debug txn content I could access.
For example I can access :
`var(txn.oauth.realm_access)`
which gives me

```
{ ["roles"] = { [1] = default-roles,[2] = offline_access,[3] = uma_authorization,} ,}
```

But if try to access `var(txn.oauth.realm_access.roles)`, I get a blank result.
What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks for your guidance